# print df.head doesn't print entire header with all the column names

Tags: printing

Am printing the head of an excel file, but while i use the line `print (df.head())` in the terminal and also in my Sublime IDE i got only first column and last one.
pls take a look below.

[image: enter image description here[![][1]]

I see those ... and i would like to see al of the info from those columns etc. Can someone pls advise how i can do this?

Comment: does anyone has a solution to this? i see that also in the Python IDE i receive the same result....